# Java Generics - Multiple Questions (Type not within bounds, Warnings)

Tags: java, generics

I have a few classes that I need to be generic. I have the following class DataSet that I want to be able to generate an average and maximum of any sort of Objects passed into class that implements my measurable interface or my Measurer interface.

When I go to test my code, I get the error that my type is not within bounds. Any ideas? When I exclude the Measurer from the DataSet, the test compiles. I am not sure if I made the DataSet correctly Generic.

DataSet.java

```
public class DataSet<T extends Measurable<Double> & Measurer<Double>>//
{
   /**
      Constructs an empty data set.
   */
   public DataSet()
   {
      this.sum = 0;
      this.count = 0;
      this.maximum = null;
   }

   /**
      Adds a data value to the data set.
      @param x a data value
   */
   public void add(T x)
   {

      sum = sum + x.getMeasure();
      if (count == 0 || maximum.getMeasure() < x.getMeasure())
      maximum = x;
      count++;
   }



   /**
      Gets the average of the added data.
      @return the average or 0 if no data has been added
   */
   public double getAverage()
   {
      if (count == 0) return 0;
      else return sum / count;
   }

   /**
      Gets the largest of the added data.
      @return the maximum or 0 if no data has been added
   */
   public T getMaximum()
   {
      return maximum;
   }

   private double sum;
   private T maximum;
   private int count;
}
```

DataSetTest.java

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class DataSetTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DataSet<BankAccount<Double>> ds1 = new DataSet<>();
        BankAccount<Double> ba1 = new BankAccount<>(100.00);
        BankAccount<Double> ba2 = new BankAccount<>(300.00);    
    }
}
```

BankAccount.java

```
public class BankAccount<T> implements Measurable<T>
{
    public BankAccount()
    {
        balance = null;
    }
    public BankAccount(T balance)
    {
        this.balance = balance;
    }
    public T getMeasure()
    {
        return balance;
    }
    private T balance;
}
```

Measurable.java

```
/**
   Describes any class whose objects can be measured.
*/
public interface Measurable <T>
{
   /**
      Computes the measure of the object.
      @return the measure
   */
   T getMeasure();
}
```

Measurer.java

```
/**
   Describes any class whose objects need a measurer.
*/
public interface Measurer <T>
{
   /**
      Computes the measurer of the object.
      @return the measurer
   */
    T getMeasurer(T anObject);

}
```

rectangleShape.java

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;

/**
Concrete Class RectangleMeasurer
@param Takes object as parameter. Overloads measurer class.
@return Returns the area of a object passed in.
*/
public class rectangleShape<T> implements Measurer<T>{
    public T getMeasurer(T anObject)
    {
        Rectangle aRectangle = (Rectangle) anObject;
        Double area = aRectangle.getWidth() * aRectangle.getHeight();

        //@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        a = (T)area;
        return a;
    }

    private T a;
}
```

Comment: Well, BankAccount doesn't implement Measurer.

Comment: Your DataSet doesn't seem to use anything out of Measurer. Are you sure you need it?

Comment: @markspace Is there a way I have have DataSet utilize methods from Measurable and Measurer and have BankAccount not require implementing Measurer?

Comment: @KarlM Yes, I also need to pass a class called rectangle into it. For it work, I need to get the area of the rectangle. I will edit the above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type bounds `<T extends Measurable<Double> & Measurer<Double>>` imply the parameter extends Measurable AND Measurer, but you want that to be OR. You can't do that with generic parameter syntax.

You can however have overloaded methods in `DataSet`.

```
public add(Measurable<Double> m) {
    //...
}

public add(Measurer<Double> m) {
    //...
}
```

Or you can do runtime type checking, although that is not the most advisable.

```
public add(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Measurable) {
        //...
    } else if (o instanceof Measurer) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Basically, your use case does not require a type parameter on the class. You are trying to make the problem fit your solution rather than the other way around.

Comment: What I really want to do is if I have a class that utilizes `int` for example, I want it to be able to use that without having to create more code for the other classes. But if I overload it like this:

`public add(Measurable<T>  m)`

I can not do any simple arithmetic within the class. I'm not sure if this was super clear.

Comment: @user2610654 you can do arithmetic if you bound `T` to `T extends Number` then use `m.doubleValue()`, which all numbers have. Of greater concern is your use of double for a currency related task - double is imprecise. Use `int` for the number of cents - that is precise (and how banks do things IRL)